# Ironport makes stack exchange sites go into loop when authentication times out

Tags: bug

The company that I work for uses Cisco IronPort between the employees and the internet.  This requires us to authenticate with our LDAP credentials to hit any site on the internet.  Occassionally it decides that we've been idle and re-prompts for authentication.

I am using a MAC running firefox 32.

When I've entered a partial answer into a stack exchange site and then go idle, I will get a popup saying that my browser is being redirected with a options to ok/cancel.  Neither option works and it goes into an endless loop making that browser window useless.

To recover from the problem, I have to open a different browser (in my case I open safari) and navigate to an internet site and enter my LDAP credentials to get Ironport to realize I am authorized.  I can then switch back to my original browser window and hit OK and everything works correctly.

Based on what I see in the Firebug net Window, it's getting a 307 Proxy Redirect response which causes that popup window.  I just got that when asking this question, but just hitting cancel to that didn't immediately pop it up.  I will have firebug active the next time I answer a question to see what is causing a looping response.

This is the popup I am talking about:
[image: Confirmation Dialog on Redirect]

Pressing Cancel on this immediately pops back up the same dialog because the answer dialog resubmits the same request again.

This is what firebug is showing:
[image]

The 200 OK comes after I navigated to a page in another browser.  It's like it's immediately retrying when it gets that 307 Proxy Redirect (and tries in a tight loop)

Comment: That popup is a standard confirm dialog merely meant to prevent you losing your work from an unintended exit from the page. How it behaves when your network is trying to continuously redirect you for being idle is something the **browser developers** should be handling. There's nothing Stack Exchange can do about it.

Comment: That dialog is the browser asking you if you want to re-submit data that you had previously submitted to that page. I can't imagine what you would have submitted to the question if you were *still typing the answer*, so I have no idea what your browser would be attempting to re-submit. It's likely something specific to your network that Stack Exchange wouldn't have control over, though.

Comment: @animuson: I *suspect* it's triggered by the AJAX heartbeat / validate requests made by the editor, which are POST requests (and therefore trigger the warning when redirected). I'm not sure why those AJAX requests don't keep the connection alive, though; that might be either a bug or an unfortunate feature in the proxy.

Comment: I think the other time I triggered this I was seeing POST answer repeatedly (the time I attached above I was able to escape because I had another browser window open).

Comment: I found a work around for this for now -- if I use the https site, ironport seems to stay out of the way (for now).